# leetcode673:why did my solution run out of time?

Tags: c++, algorithm, time-complexity, dynamic-programming

Leetcode 673:
Given an integer array nums, return the number of longest increasing subsequences.
Notice that the sequence has to be strictly increasing.
And here is my code:

```
class Solution {
//recursively compute the max increasing subsequence length and number of them at a given start point
//and a Min which means the next value must be at least Min.The result will be recorded on dp and values in
//dp will be checked first
    pair<int,int> length_and_count(int ptr,int Min,vector<int>& nums,vector<unordered_map<int,pair<int,int>>>& dp){
        if(ptr==nums.size())
        return make_pair(0,1);
        if(dp[ptr].find(Min)!=dp[ptr].end()){
            return dp[ptr][Min];
        } 
        else{
            if(nums[ptr]<Min)
            return dp[ptr][Min]=length_and_count(ptr+1,Min,nums,dp);
            else{
                auto pair1=length_and_count(ptr+1,Min,nums,dp),pair2=length_and_count(ptr+1,nums[ptr]+1,nums,dp);
                if(pair1.first>++pair2.first)
                return dp[ptr][Min]=pair1;
                else if(pair1.first<pair2.first)
                return dp[ptr][Min]=pair2;
                else return dp[ptr][Min]=make_pair(pair1.first,pair1.second+pair2.second);
            }
        }
    } 
public:
    int findNumberOfLIS(vector<int>& nums) {
        vector<unordered_map<int,pair<int,int>>> dp(nums.size());
        return length_and_count(0,INT_MIN,nums,dp).second;
    }
};
```

I think my solution is of complexity O(n2), because my dp parameters are the start point of nums and the current max value, which is got from the vector,so the size of dp can not be bigger than the square of the input vector.Since the problem size is less than 2000,my solution should be of 10s of ms.So whats's wrong with my solution?

Comment: The algorithm looks good, but check the obvious things anyway: 1) are you compiling with optimizations; 2) profile your code and see where you're losing time

Comment: "my solution should be" Have you tested it?

Comment: Note that your code creates a few million `unordered_map` entries. They are  cheap but not free.

Comment: Trying it for myself with an arbitrary array of size 2000 indeed returns in less than a second.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for very interesting question! Was glad to implement my own solution for it, and to improve speed of yours.

On test of random input of 2000 elements I improved speed of your solution `8x-9x` times. For that I did following things:

1. Interchanged order of vector and unordered_map, by making `dp` structure `unordered_map<int, shared_ptr<vector<pair<int, int>>>>`. This way we can later reuse pointer to `Min` entry of unordered map, by passing this entry downwards to recursive function.
2. In `dp` wrapped vector into [std::shared_ptr](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr). This allows to be sure that vector will not change memory location even if unordered map grows.
3. Instead of doing same unordered map search again with `dp[ptr][Min]` I did search just once inside single call of function through `.find(Min)` and reused this iterator later in all other places of a function.
4. Passed `Min_vec` pointer down to all recursive calls, so that other function calls don't search inside unordered map again for same `Min` entry. Just single place was not reusing this pointer, where `nums[ptr] + 1` was passed as Min.
5. Created special lambda function `GetMinVec()` which finds and returns pointer to Min entry. In case if this entry didn't exist yet I initialize it by allocating shared_ptr and resizing vector to size of `nums.size()` filled with `pair(-1, -1)` which signifies empty value.

All steps above boosted your solution by `8x-9x` times. Your original solution is located in my code as `SolutionOriginal` class. While my boosted variant is `SolutionBoosted`.

Also I created my own solution that is `100x` faster than your original and `11x-12x` faster than boosted original. This new solution I called `SolutionSqrt`. It works as follows:

1. Lets create `K = sqrt(N)` buckets. Each of `K` buckets will have around `K` elements on average at the end.
2. Each bucket will help us to narrow search of all elements that are smaller than current one. For each new number we will find the bucket index `buck_i` that says that all buckets with smaller index contain elements not bigger than current.
3. Inside current bucket `buck_i` we will do linear search to find all elements that are smaller than current.
4. Each bucket contains a [Heap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heap_(data_structure)) array that grows by using [std::push_heap](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/push_heap). This Heap is sorted in such a way that its first element (head) contains largest element.
5. Bucket's Heap is sorted in such a way that first element has longest chain of numbers located in this heap.
6. We do `Sqrt(N) + Sqrt(N)` searches on average for each new number. And we search how can we extend current longest chain by adding this new element.
7. If longest chain is succeded to be prolonged then we remember new maximal length and new maximal count of current bucket `buck_i`. Also then new element becomes first Heap element as providing the longest chain.
8. Each bucket has its own length of longest chain and count of such chains formed.
9. Overall complexity of such algorithm is `O(N * Sqrt(N))`. This complexity can be improved even further if instead of 2-level buckets we make 3-level buckets in this case we will achieve complexity `O(N * N^(1/3))`. This `O(N * Sqrt(N))` complexity is much less than original OP's code that is `O(N^2)`.

I did timings of all 3 variants of solutions on random test set of 2000 numbers. Timings can be seen after the code.

[Try it online!](https://godbolt.org/z/8EYoTrYxc)

```cpp
#include <cstdint>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <cmath>
#include <limits>

class SolutionSqrt {
public:
    using u64 = uint64_t;
    using NumT = int;
    u64 findNumberOfLIS(std::vector<NumT> const & nums) {
        size_t const
            N = nums.size(),
            nbucks = std::max<size_t>(1, std::llround(std::sqrt(N))),
            buck_size = (N + nbucks - 1) / nbucks;
        std::vector<size_t> si(N), rsi(N), ll(N);
        std::vector<u64> lc(N);
        for (size_t i = 0; i < si.size(); ++i)
            si[i] = i;
        std::sort(si.begin(), si.end(), [&](size_t a, size_t b){
            return nums[a] < nums[b];
        });
        for (size_t i = 0; i < rsi.size(); ++i)
            rsi[si[i]] = i;
        struct Buck {
            std::vector<size_t> sj;
            size_t max_ll = 0;
            u64 max_lc = 0;
            NumT max_num = std::numeric_limits<NumT>::min(),
                 min_num = std::numeric_limits<NumT>::max();
        };
        std::vector<Buck> bucks(nbucks);
        for (size_t i = 0; i < N; ++i) {
            auto const num = nums[i];
            size_t const buck_i = rsi[i] / buck_size;
            size_t max_ll = 0;
            for (size_t j = 0; j <= buck_i; ++j) {
                auto const & buckj = bucks[j];
                if (buckj.sj.empty())
                    continue;
                if (j < buck_i && buckj.max_num < num)
                    max_ll = std::max(max_ll, buckj.max_ll);
                else {
                    if (buckj.min_num == buckj.max_num && buckj.max_num == num)
                        continue;
                    for (size_t k = 0; k < buckj.sj.size(); ++k)
                        if (nums[buckj.sj[k]] < num)
                            max_ll = std::max(max_ll, ll[buckj.sj[k]]);
                }
            }
            if (max_ll > 0) {
                u64 clc = 0;
                for (size_t j = 0; j <= buck_i; ++j) {
                    auto const & buckj = bucks[j];
                    if (buckj.sj.empty())
                        continue;
                    if (j < buck_i && buckj.max_num < num) {
                        if (ll[buckj.sj[0]] == max_ll)
                            clc += buckj.max_lc;
                    } else {
                        if (buckj.min_num == buckj.max_num && buckj.max_num == num)
                            continue;
                        for (size_t k = 0; k < buckj.sj.size(); ++k)
                            if (nums[buckj.sj[k]] < num && ll[buckj.sj[k]] == max_ll)
                                clc += lc[buckj.sj[k]];
                    }
                }
                ll[i] = max_ll + 1;
                lc[i] = clc;
            } else {
                ll[i] = 1;
                lc[i] = 1;
            }
            auto & buck = bucks[buck_i];
            bool const new_max = buck.sj.empty() || ll[i] > ll[buck.sj[0]];
            buck.sj.push_back(i);
            std::push_heap(buck.sj.begin(), buck.sj.end(), [&](size_t a, size_t b){
                return ll[a] < ll[b];
            });
            if (ll[i] >= buck.max_ll)
                buck.max_lc = lc[i] + (new_max ? u64(0) : buck.max_lc);
            buck.max_ll = std::max(buck.max_ll, ll[i]);
            buck.min_num = std::min(buck.min_num, num);
            buck.max_num = std::max(buck.max_num, num);
        }
        size_t total_max_ll = 0;
        for (size_t i = 0; i < bucks.size(); ++i)
            if (!bucks[i].sj.empty())
                total_max_ll = std::max(total_max_ll, bucks[i].max_ll);
        u64 total_lc = 0;
        for (size_t i = 0; i < bucks.size(); ++i)
            if (!bucks[i].sj.empty() && ll[bucks[i].sj[0]] == total_max_ll)
                total_lc += bucks[i].max_lc;

        //std::cout << "Length " << total_max_ll << std::endl;
        //std::cout << "Count " << total_lc << std::endl;

        return total_lc;
    }
};

#include <unordered_map>
#include <climits>
#include <memory>

using namespace std;

class SolutionOriginal {
    // recursively compute the max increasing subsequence length and number of them at a given start point
    // and a Min which means the next value must be at least Min.The result will be recorded on dp and values in
    // dp will be checked first
    pair<int, int> length_and_count(int ptr, int Min, vector<int> & nums,
                                    vector<unordered_map<int, pair<int, int>>> & dp) {
        if (ptr == nums.size())
            return make_pair(0, 1);
        if (dp[ptr].find(Min) != dp[ptr].end()) {
            return dp[ptr][Min];
        } else {
            if (nums[ptr] < Min)
                return dp[ptr][Min] = length_and_count(ptr + 1, Min, nums, dp);
            else {
                auto pair1 = length_and_count(ptr + 1, Min, nums, dp),
                     pair2 = length_and_count(ptr + 1, nums[ptr] + 1, nums, dp);
                if (pair1.first > ++pair2.first)
                    return dp[ptr][Min] = pair1;
                else if (pair1.first < pair2.first)
                    return dp[ptr][Min] = pair2;
                else
                    return dp[ptr][Min] = make_pair(pair1.first, pair1.second + pair2.second);
            }
        }
    }

  public:
    int findNumberOfLIS(vector<int> nums) {
        vector<unordered_map<int, pair<int, int>>> dp(nums.size());
        auto p = length_and_count(0, INT_MIN, nums, dp);
        // std::cout << "Length " << p.first << std::endl;
        // std::cout << "Count " << p.second << std::endl;
        return p.second;
    }
};

class SolutionBoosted {
    // recursively compute the max increasing subsequence length and number of them at a given start point
    // and a Min which means the next value must be at least Min.The result will be recorded on dp and values in
    // dp will be checked first
    pair<int, int> length_and_count(int ptr, int Min, vector<int> & nums,
            unordered_map<int, shared_ptr<vector<pair<int, int>>>> & dp,
            vector<pair<int, int>> * Min_vec = nullptr) {
        if (ptr == nums.size())
            return make_pair(0, 1);
        auto GetMinVec = [&]{
            auto it0 = dp.find(Min);
            if (it0 != dp.end())
                return it0->second.get();

            auto it1 = dp.insert(make_pair(Min, make_shared<
                vector<pair<int, int>>>())).first;
            it1->second->resize(nums.size(), make_pair(-1, -1));
            return it1->second.get();
        };
        if (!Min_vec)
            Min_vec = GetMinVec();
        auto & e = (*Min_vec)[ptr];
        if (e.first != -1)
            return e;
        else {
            if (nums[ptr] < Min)
                return e = length_and_count(ptr + 1, Min, nums, dp, Min_vec);
            else {
                auto pair1 = length_and_count(ptr + 1, Min, nums, dp, Min_vec),
                     pair2 = length_and_count(ptr + 1, nums[ptr] + 1, nums, dp);
                if (pair1.first > ++pair2.first)
                    return e = pair1;
                else if (pair1.first < pair2.first)
                    return e = pair2;
                else
                    return e = make_pair(
                        pair1.first, pair1.second + pair2.second);
            }
        }
    }

  public:
    int findNumberOfLIS(vector<int> nums) {
        unordered_map<int, shared_ptr<vector<pair<int, int>>>> dp;
        auto p = length_and_count(0, INT_MIN, nums, dp);
        // std::cout << "Length " << p.first << std::endl;
        // std::cout << "Count " << p.second << std::endl;
        return p.second;
    }
};

#include <random>
#include <chrono>

int main() {
    std::mt19937_64 rng(123);
    std::uniform_int_distribution<int> distr(-100, 100);
    std::vector<int> v;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < (1 << 11); ++i)
        v.push_back(distr(rng));
    {
        auto tb = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
        std::cout << "Sqrt " << SolutionSqrt().findNumberOfLIS(v) << "  ";
        std::cout << "Time " << std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::microseconds>(
            std::chrono::system_clock::now() - tb).count() / 1000000.0 << " sec" << std::endl;
    }
    {
        auto tb = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
        std::cout << "Original "
            << SolutionOriginal().findNumberOfLIS(v) << "  ";
        std::cout << "Time " << std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::microseconds>(
            std::chrono::system_clock::now() - tb).count() / 1000000.0 << " sec" << std::endl;
    }
    {
        auto tb = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
        std::cout << "Original_Boosted "
            << SolutionBoosted().findNumberOfLIS(v) << "  ";
        std::cout << "Time " << std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::microseconds>(
            std::chrono::system_clock::now() - tb).count() / 1000000.0 << " sec" << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Sqrt 15240960  Time 0.000856 sec
Original 15240960  Time 0.081954 sec
Original_Boosted 15240960  Time 0.011343 sec
```